# Show / Hide Divs via anchor links in a navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navbar that uses anchor links to connect to different divs. I have all the div's hidden, but I want them to show based on what link you click.

```
<!-- NAV CONTAINER -->
<div class="navContainer">  
  <nav class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
     <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#page1">Overview</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- DIV CONTAINER -->
<div class="container">

<div class="sections" id="home">
homepage with title here 
</div>

<div class="sections" id="page1">
page 1
</div>
</div>
```

I know you can do it using jQuery but I haven't been able to make anything work. Right now the divs are set to display:none. 'Home' should appear when you load the site.

Comment: You say you have tried...show us what you tried in a JSFiddle and we can correct/improve that.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to use the css pseudo-selector `:target`

```
.sections {display:none;}
.sections:target {display:block;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CHb5w/)

[CSS3 selectors are pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) but `:target` can give odd or buggy behaviour as mentioned here: http://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Comment: This is nice, and being a pure CSS solution has it's benefits too.

Comment: This is great, my one question would be how to have it start on the #home div

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control it with jQuery... try it:  http://jsfiddle.net/luiggi/kRgt6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.home").click(function () {
        $("#home").toggle();
        $("#page1").hide();
    });

    $("li.overview").click(function () {
        $("#page1").toggle();
        $("#home").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to add some sort of CSS class to the anchor links so you can find the specific triggers more easily.

Just from memory, the code will be something like this (assuming anchors have the "ToggleDiv" class name).

```
$('.ToggleDiv').each(function(el){
     var divId = $(el).attr("href");
     $(el).click(function(){
         $(divId).Toggle();
     });
})
```